# Conventions for amount of detail to put in Python exception messages?

Tags: python, exception, conventions

I am trying to determine some guidelines for how to write exception messages.

For example, let us suppose a hypothetical function which must receive a constant number of bytes (as a `bytes` object), and we call it with `[1, 2, 3]`. The following are all potential exceptions:

```
1. TypeError
2. TypeError: argument must be 16 bytes
3. TypeError: argument must be 16 bytes; got 'list'
4. TypeError: argument must be 16 bytes; got 'list' [1, 2, 3]
```

Generally, I feel that the message should always explain the condition that wasn't met, but I'm on the fence about how much information to include about the offending object.

Are there any guidelines on this subject?

Comment: Quick link that you might find relevant: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/29433/how-to-write-a-good-exception-message

Comment: Also a good read, though it is written for Java: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/entarch/effective-exceptions2-097044.html . The distinction drawn between 'Contingincies' and 'Faults' is what I was getting at with the notion of 'Context' in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Excellent question!

When I am generally creating custom exceptions I usually go look at the Python set which is generally exhaustive.

Now as for the question as to provide how much detail, I wouldn't make them too specific because you don't know what would be triggering them or causing them.

In example:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

is descriptive enough to let me know that the `+` operator isn't supported, I don't need know to know what the string contains.

So in your example first two are perfectly fine, second two are overkill IMO.

Goodluck.

Comment: Your example seems to point at the third on my list, in which the message describes the types of the offending objects, even if not their value.

But you say it is overkill?

Comment: I guess looking at it again number 3 would be alright too, but it often clear what I am passing into a function. (+) operand can be between any two type, which is why its good to show which ones.

Comment: @MikeBoers: I'd say that the thing about `+` is that the type(s) accepted on the right depend on the type on the left. So the exception quoted couldn't say, "requires numeric", because it's not clear which operand is "wrong". With your hypothetical example you're explicitly testing the type of a specific argument, you know exactly what you need, so it's less important to provide information about the wrong value. That said, overkill rarely does any harm. Including the type in the error message is unlikely to go wrong. Including the value could cause problems if `unicode(bad_value)` throws!

Answer (score 1):

I don't have much in the way of 'established idiom' links to give you, but here are my 2¢:

Your goal is for the poor sap who encouters the exception (i.e. possibly not you and/or far in the future) to have enough information to understand the problem, and hopefully fix it.

Information is communicated through exceptions in several ways:

- Stack trace - You get this for free.
- Exception type - There is some art to choosing the right type, and deciding when it is appropriate to make your own more specific exception type.
- Message - The part you're asking about.

You should also consider:

- Context - How is this exception intended to be used? Is it a critical error where you want maximum information possible, or is it a transient condition that clients may well want to handle in their code, and the debugging information is not so important? If your exception will likely be handled by client code, you will probably want to put your information into an easily machine-readable format, rather than a text message. For instance, have an error code enum field.

But generally, I think it's best to ask yourself: "If I got this exception in production code, what information would I want available to me?"

Personally, in the example you give, I'd go for option (4) every time. I don't think that's too much information. Your exception seems like something that should pretty much never be happening, and if it does happen, you want to know exactly what went wrong.

If you leave out information, as in (1-3), you provide an opportunity for confusion about what's really going on.

Don't give redundant information in messages - don't be verbose just for the sake of it. But communicate all relevant information for the benefit of that future maintainer who is scratching their head.